# Как настроить WebSocket на локальной машине?

Tags: websocket, openserver

Использовал не одну ([1](https://code.google.com/archive/p/phpwebsocket/),[2](http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/php-and-html5-websocket-server-and-client-communication/)) готовую реализацию. По идее все должно работать и в самом коде ошибок нет. К тому же к echo.websocket.org нормально подключается, значит проблема с серверной стороной. А именно в следующем:

При попытке подключиться к моему сокету выбивает

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8000/server.php' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Возможно, все из-за порта, который никто не открыл, что и не дает сделать OpenServer. После редактирования `httpd.conf` значения все равно меняются на прежние.

И при попытке подключиться к порту 80:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost/server.php' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 200
```

Cколько удалось нагуглить, все говорится о том, что ничего не мешает подключиться к 80 порту, но в итоге просто возвращает код 200.

По второму примеру в логи пишет:

```
socket_bind() failed: An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions.
socket_listen() failed: An invalid argument was supplied.
Server started on 127.0.0.1 : 80
```

Comment: Может у вас сетевой экран стоит или антивирус?

Comment: Отключал, все та же картина, при том на хостинге то же самое

Comment: @Ni55aN Смотрите, у меня тоже проблема с этим. Вот что мне удалось собрать - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/512116/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%81%D0%B2%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8C-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC-websocket

Comment: @Ni55aN На 80-м порту по умолчанию рабоатет openserver, так что порт должен быть занят. Если вы его займете вебсокетом, то не сможете включить оперсервер.

Comment: Я точно не уверен, но по идеи нужно так подключаться - `ws://localhost:8080` А перед этим запустить сервер , например через консоль открытую от администратора - `php bin/server.php`

Answer (score 1):

Подключаться надо по адресу `ws://localhost:8000` без `/server.php`

Comment: Или `ws://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: SDarkness
Почему вы решили, что подключаться надо по адресу ws://localhost:8000, где это настроенно. ws://127.0.0.1:8000 это одно и тоже. Если что-то советуете, то давайте хоть какое-то пояснение.

Comment: Для openserver, а на хостиге уже использовать адрес сайта, ну так же можно использовать адрес сайта ws://домен:8000 в обоих случаях.